# How to define/declare and use variable in Squirrel SQL client 3

Tags: sql, oracle, squirrel-sql

I use the software SQuirreL SQL Client Version 3.2.1 and I want to declare variable like

```
define dateFrom = '13/04/2012';
define dateTo = '13/04/2012'
```

And to use it in my sql query like that

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TRUNC(column_name) BETWEEN to_date('&dateFrom','YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('&dateTo','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I define and use variable in SQuirreL.

Comment: SQuirreL is a client, not the actual RDBMS. What RDBMS are you calling? That is, the variable will be declared in the SQL you send from SQuirreL to the RDBMS

Comment: I'm calling a Oracle database.

Comment: What error message are you getting? The format mask reads 'YYYY-MM-DD', whereas your constant values are formatted 'DD/MM/YYYY'. Did you try that format in the query?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite what you want, but have you tried loading plugin 'sqlparam'? It offers variable substition, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TRUNC(column_name) BETWEEN :dateFrom and :dataTo
```

When running this query Squirrel will ask for values.

Comment: Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old but it helped me find a solution and I thought I'd share it. Using SquirrelSQL 3.8.1 this works when running against an oracle database.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TRUNC(column_name) BETWEEN to_date( :dateFrom ,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date( :dateTo,'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Note: The space between the the function call and the bind variable colon is needed -- without it you will get an error.

Answer (score -1):

"SQuirreL (just like Oracle's SQL-Plus) needs to know when you have finished
your anonymous procedure.  That is usually done by adding a line at the end
of your procedure with a sinlge slash  (/) character.  For example:"

```
DECLARE
v1  NUMBER(3);

BEGIN
  v1 := 3;
  select 1 from dual
END;
/
```

Please look here: http://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/mailman/message/28580491/

Now when you select your SQL including the slash you will be able to run it with Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: The select requires an into portion and is missing the semicolon at the end. But this will not return any value in its current form.